# ISAPI Filter not working on Windows 2008 R2 64-bit

Tags: filter, windows-server-2008-r2, isapi

I have developed an ISAPI filter which runs fine on 32-bit. I also compiled it for 64-bit using VS2005 cross-compiler. But when I am trying to run it on Windows 2008 R2 64-bit server with IIS-7.5, it does not work. It seems filter dll has been loaded but IIS is not doing anything with it. I used the following command to check this.

tasklist /m mydll*

Any suggestions what

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular reason you need the DLL to be 64 bit?  I've been able to run 32 bit ISAPI filters on a 64 bit machine by doing the following:

- Make sure the IIS application pool is set to allow 32 bit applications (this is off by default)
- Register the DLL using the 32 bit version of regsvr32: C:\Windows\SysWow64\regsvr32.exe
- Verify that the DLL isn't missing any dependencies by using Dependency Walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the reason is that there is another ISAPI filter running which is 64-bit, so I have to make it compatible with 64-bit. The steps you suggested are therefore cannot be applied, although I tried that as well and the other filter stopped running. Anyway my problem is solved, I don't know how but I  played with some settings and it worked. I am trying to figure out the actual problem. Will post it if found for other users. Thanks :)

Comment: I know I'm late, but you just saved my life. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us the settings you changed?

Answer (score 1):

For 64 bit, the problem is the registry:
The problem I was
for 32 bit the location of apache redirector in registry is: 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Jakarta Isapi Redirector\1.0]

but for 64 bitlocation must be:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Jakarta Isapi Redirector\1.0]

Note the  "Wow6432Node".

so just re-create the 32 bit on the Wow6432Node and then you are set.